# Gzip compression and cache expiration not working

Tags: .htaccess, xampp, gzip, cache-expiration

I have configured cache expiration and gzip compression in .htaccess file but its not working according to yslow chrome extension stats.

Here is my **.htaccess**

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Mod Rewrite
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# gZip Compression
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Expires headers (for better cache control)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on

# Your document html
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"

# Media: images, video, audio
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"

# CSS and JavaScript
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Note: I'm using Xampp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my first post here!

For cache expiration:

Did you check if the module "mod_expires.so" is enabled in apache/conf/httpd.conf?
Search for the line `#LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so`and remove the "#" sign. After that it should work.

For gzip compression:

I use "mod_deflate" to enable compression. I also use "mod_mime", "mod_setenvif" and "mod_headers". Check each be enabled in httpd.conf. This combination works for me.

Htaccess my compression:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
 AddType application/x-javascript .js
 AddType text/css .css
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
 SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
 <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:rar|zip)$ no-gzip dont-vary
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpg|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:avi|mov|mp4)$ no-gzip dont-vary
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.mp3$ no-gzip dont-vary
 </IfModule>
 <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
 </IfModule>
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
 </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

More information [here](http://howtounix.info/howto/Apache-gzip-compression-with-mod_deflate). I hope that helps.